# Does googlebot interact with the <select> or <input type="submit"> inside <form method="post">?

Tags: html, seo, googlebot

**Background of Problem:**

I have a search page that allows users to select their search criteria using a `<select>`.  Once the user has selected their desired criterias, the user can then click the search button which will navigate to a new page and return results based on their selected criteria.  The submit button is a `<input type="submit">` inside `<form method="post">`.

The problem is I do not want google touching any of the `<select>` or `<input type="submit">` inside `<form method="post">` as both elements have ajax get/post attached to them.  Furthermore, I also do not want google to index the result pages of the search.

I have specified in robots.txt to block web-crawlers from navigating to the results page but I want to ensure that they are not playing around with any of the menus or submit buttons.  After doing some reading, apparently googlebot is capable of selecting options from select menus as well as submitting forms.

**Here is a link of where I read this from:**

http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.ca/2008/04/crawling-through-html-forms.html

http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.ca/2011/11/get-post-and-safely-surfacing-more-of.html

**Question:**

1. Does googlebot interact with the `<select>` or `<input type="submit">` inside `<form method="post">`
2. If yes, is there any way to prevent googlebot from touching any of the `<select>` or `<input type="submit">` inside `<form method="post">`

Comment: I don't think Google bot does these clicks. It navigates to the pages and reads meta information and text available on those pages.

Comment: I edited my post form earlier to include a link where I got my assumption from.

Comment: "We take precautions to avoid performing any task on a site that could result in executing an unintended user action. Our POSTs are primarily for crawling resources that a page requests automatically, mimicking what a typical user would see when they open the URL in their browser. ".  I think this answers.

Comment: But I was reading elsewhere that apparently googlebot was capable of filling forms, and submitting forms. http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.ca/2008/04/crawling-through-html-forms.html  This link better describes what I was talking about.

Comment: Sorry if I am making things difficult for you, I just want to make sure that web-crawlers aren't able to play around with the buttons and menus on the page.

Comment: If not Google bots, some other bots (malicious). If you are really concerned about bots, you need to add proper hardening to prevent any actions. In my opinion, Google bots might not do that (even though they are capable of).

Comment: What do you mean by proper hardening?  Btw, thanks for the quick replies :)

Comment: Examples, without logged user session, don't submit to server. Add a captcha to make sure action being performed by user etc.

Comment: Oh okay, I get what you mean.  What do I do with this post now?  Do I just leave it there or do I delete it?  Sorry I am not familiar with stackoverflow etiquette.

Comment: Just leave it there for few days. If there is no concrete answer from any other members, I would delete it.

Comment: The way how you formulated the question gives a strong impression that you're unfamiliar with basic HTTP/HTML, and that you're not understanding that JSF is in the context of this question irrelevant as it's basically a HTML code generator. I fixed the question, but I strongly recommend to work on your fundamental web development knowledge.